# request module is causing the command line to crash

Tags: node.js, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to use the request module in Node.js to get the current price of bitcoins using APIs from bitcoinaverage.com. When I launch it on localhost:3000, I get the page and the HTML is working fine. My page works sometimes and gives me the data but most of the time the server crashes. Sometimes it works, I don't know what my mistake is. Note: No proxies are enabled.

```js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const https = require("https");
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.get("/", function (req, res) {

    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});
app.post("/", function (req, res) {

    request("https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/indices/global/ticker/BTCUSD", function (error,
        response, body) {
        var data = JSON.parse(body);
        var price = data.last;
        var priceAverage = data.averages.week;
        res.send("<h1>The price of a Bitcoin now is " + price + "</h1>");
        console.log(price);
        console.log(priceAverage);
        console.log(response.statusCode);
    });
});
```

The console is showing me the following:

```
Unauthenticated requests are not allowed. Take out a new plan or start a free trial at https://pro.bitcoinaverage.com
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token U in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Request._callback (/Users/Desktop/Web Development/Bitcoin-Ticker/index.js:60:18)
    at Request.self.callback (/Users/Desktop/Web Development/Bitcoin-Ticker/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/Web Development/Bitcoin-Ticker/node_modules/request/request.js:1154:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/Desktop/Web Development/Bitcoin-Ticker/node_modules/request/request.js:1076:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:28)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1220:12)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: First: What error your console shows? Second: You are not checking for errors. That's as must. The `error` argument is not there for decoration.

Comment: "Unauthenticated requests are not allowed" - your requests are failing and you're getting an error, which you're not handling, so your `Express` application crashes.